# Instead of Arabic text showing boxes in Android App

Tags: android, multilingual, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have some Arabic text in PDF file. I copied and pasted in Android Studio. It shows some special characters in Android Studio. When I run it in blue stack then it shows some boxes. I am attaching all three view. Thanks for your help.

[Arabic text copied from this PDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s89EX.png)

[Arabic text shown as boxes/special characters in blue stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuGYH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Bidi](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Bidi.html) class and change encoding to `UTF-8`. for this.